# How can I add new value in class object

Tags: python, openstack-horizon

I have a list with class objects. To this class object I need to add a new value. How it is possible without creating a new class.

Sample List follows

```
 [<hashmap.Mapping {u'field_id': u'409231ab-0809-4e50-9ad1-7c75f79720b4', u'value': u'12fabdf1e7744e91b0a1c3ee511f876d', u'mapping_id': u'e2e65bcc-12ce-4384-89e5-318ba1c057f7', u'cost': u'1.02003000', u'service_id': None, u'group_id': u'71d36a0f-6d22-4780-839f-b69829db9929', u'type': u'flat'}>]
```

And I need the following list

```
[<hashmap.Mapping {u'name': u'tenant addon', u'field_id': u'409231ab-0809-4e50-9ad1-7c75f79720b4', u'value': u'12fabdf1e7744e91b0a1c3ee511f876d', u'mapping_id': u'e2e65bcc-12ce-4384-89e5-318ba1c057f7', u'cost': u'1.02003000', u'service_id': None, u'group_id': u'71d36a0f-6d22-4780-839f-b69829db9929', u'type': u'flat'}>]
```

Thanks In Advance
Binoy

Comment: Please give us more context, like some code for example.

Comment: Hi @Klaus D
Actually I am working with openstack horizon. In that my API call gives the below output. 

{code}
 [<hashmap.Mapping {u'field_id': u'409231ab-0809-4e50-9ad1-7c75f79720b4', u'value': u'12fabdf1e7744e91b0a1c3ee511f876d', u'mapping_id': u'e2e65bcc-12ce-4384-89e5-318ba1c057f7', u'cost': u'1.02003000', u'service_id': None, u'group_id': u'71d36a0f-6d22-4780-839f-b69829db9929', u'type': u'flat'}>]

and I want to add one more data into this class object. Is it possible ?

Comment: Hi @Klaus D

There is no specific code for this. I just want to update the class object with a key value pair. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question. Adding new value to the class object is done using the setattr() method. The sample output given is

```
[<hashmap.Mapping {u'field_id': u'409231ab-0809-4e50-9ad1-7c75f79720b4', u'value': u'12fabdf1e7744e91b0a1c3ee511f876d', u'mapping_id': u'e2e65bcc-12ce-4384-89e5-318ba1c057f7', u'cost': u'1.02003000', u'service_id': None, u'group_id': u'71d36a0f-6d22-4780-839f-b69829db9929', u'type': u'flat'}>]
```

Actually this is a list of class object. To this object we can add new value using the following method.
a) Define new list
b) Iterate the present list
c) Add the new value using setattr()
d) Append the list into new list

code is follows

```
#Iterating the mapp data
    for mapp in mappings:

        #Getting the groups
        setattr(mapp, 'service_name', 'test')
        map_list.append(maps)
```

This will give the following output

```
[<hashmap.Mapping {u'field_id': u'409231ab-0809-4e50-9ad1-7c75f79720b4', u'value': u'12fabdf1e7744e91b0a1c3ee511f876d', u'mapping_id': u'e2e65bcc-12ce-4384-89e5-318ba1c057f7', u'cost': u'1.02003000', u'service_id': None, u'group_id': u'71d36a0f-6d22-4780-839f-b69829db9929', u'type': u'flat', u'service_name': u'test'}>
```